# How to combine two query in single query in mysql byusing subquery or inner query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select sub.sub_product_image_path, sub.sub_product_id 
    from `portal_products(sub category)` sub , 
         `portal_products(main category)`main 
  where sub.product_id=main.product_id ;

select sub.sub_product_image_path, sub.sub_product_id 
    from `portal_products(sub category)` sub  
  where sub.product_id=35;
```

Comment: use Union or Union All

Comment: To describe 'portal_products(sub category)' as a poor choice for a table name would be an understatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work if i am getting your requirement correct

```
select sub.sub_product_image_path,sub.sub_product_id 
 from `portal_products(sub category)` sub 
 inner join  `portal_products(main category)`main  on
 sub.product_id=main.product_id 
 where sub.product_id=35;
```

OR

```
select sub.sub_product_image_path, sub.sub_product_id 
from `portal_products(sub category)` sub , 
inner join `portal_products(main category)`main  on sub.product_id=main.product_id ;

union  all

select sub.sub_product_image_path, sub.sub_product_id 
from `portal_products(sub category)` sub  
where sub.product_id=35
```